# Spring Data JPA Interface and class based projection not working for DISTINCT field of Embedded key

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Following is my entity structure. EmployeeKey is an EmbeddedId(composite key) within Employee.

This is the native query I want to implement using Spring-Data.

```
select DISTINCT(ID), NAME, DEPARTMENT from EMPLOYEE;
```

I am trying to use **Interface based and Class based Spring data JPA projections** but none of the approaches seem to work. Interface-based projections give List of proxies which I am unable to unproxy. Using **DISTINCT** in constructor of Class-based Projections is not possible AFAIK.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
   @EmbeddedId
   private EmployeeKey key;

   @Column(name = "NAME")
   private String name;

   @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT")
   private String department;

   @Coulmn(name = "AGE")
   private Integer age;

   //Getter/Setters/Constructors
}

@Embeddable
public class EmployeeKey {
   @Column(name = "ID")
   String id;

   @Column(name = "REGNO")
   String regNo;

   //Getter/Setters/Constructors
}

@Repository
public interface EmployeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, EmployeeKey>{
   @Query(value = "select distinct(emp.key.id), emp.name, emp.department from Employee emp")
   List<EmployeeInterfaceProjection> findUsingInterfaceProjection();

   @Query(value = "select distinct(emp.key.id) as empId, emp.name as empName, emp.department as empDepartment from Employee emp")
   List<EmployeeClassProjection1> findUsingClassProjection1();

   @Query(value = "select new com.path.to.EmployeeClassProjection2(emp.key, emp.name, emp.department) from Employee emp")
   List<EmployeeClassProjection2> findUsingClassProjection2();

   @Query(value = "select distinct(emp.key.id) as empId, emp.name as empName, emp.department as empDepartment from Employee emp")
   List<Object[]> findUsingObjectProjection();
}

public interface EmployeeInterfaceProjection{
   EmployeeKeyInterfaceProjection getKey();
   String getName();
   String getDepartment();

   interface EmployeeKeyInterfaceProjection{
      String getId();
   }
}

public class EmployeeClassProjection1{
   private String empId;
   private String empName;
   private String empDepartment;

   //Getters/Setters, Constructors, Hashcode, Equals
}

public class EmployeeClassProjection2{
   private EmployeeKey key;
   private String name;
   private String department;

   //Getters/Setters, Constructors, Hashcode, Equals
}
```

**PROBLEMS FACED IN EACH APPROACH**

**findUsingInterfaceProjection()**

This gives a **List which I am unable to unproxy to get the value**. Hibernate.unproxy/initialize doesn't help either. While streaming on the proxies and calling getters: getKey(), getName(), getDepartment() gives null for each.

**findUsingClassProjection1()**

This gives "No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.**AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap**] to type [com.path.to.EmployeeClassProjection1]" error.

I know in order to resolve this I need to use a parameterized constructor directly within the query. But doing so prohibits me from using **DISTINCT** in the constructor.

**findUsingClassProjection2()**

This approach actually gets the data and not the proxies but i need the distinct filtration. Can't use DISTINCT within the contructor in query.

**findUsingObjectProjection()**

This works fine but looks like a very crude approach. I was hoping to use the JPA projections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what finally worked for me. I used **column aliases in the query** matching the getter method names in projection (alias = **name**, if projection has **getName()**). There is **no need to use an inner interface EmployeeKeyInterfaceProjection**.

```
public interface EmployeeInterfaceProjection{
   String getId();
   String getName();
   String getDepartment();
}


@Query(value = "select distinct(emp.key.id) as id, emp.name as name, emp.department as department from Employee emp")
List<EmployeeInterfaceProjection> findUsingInterfaceProjection();
```

Interface based projections internally work on **AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap**. Ealier, without using column aliases, I got null for each of getId(), getName(), getDepartment(). Using aliases solves this issue.

Thanks @Ho Wai Chan for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, EmployeeKey>{
   @Query(value = "select distinct(emp.key.id) as id, emp.name, emp.department from Employee emp")
   List<EmployeeInterfaceProjection> findUsingInterfaceProjection();

   @Query(value = "select distinct(emp.key.id) as empId, emp.name as empName, emp.department as empDepartment from Employee emp")
   List<EmployeeClassProjection1> findUsingClassProjection1();

   @Query(value = "select new com.path.to.EmployeeClassProjection2(emp.key, emp.name, emp.department) from Employee emp")
   List<EmployeeClassProjection2> findUsingClassProjection2();

   @Query(value = "select distinct(emp.key.id) as empId, emp.name as empName, emp.department as empDepartment from Employee emp")
   List<Object[]> findUsingObjectProjection();
}

public interface EmployeeInterfaceProjection{
   String getId();
   String getName();
   String getDepartment();

}

public interface EmployeeClassProjection1{
   String getEmpId;
   String getEmpName;
   String getEmpDepartment;
}
```

if you want to get the inner object:

```
public interface dto {
    @Value("#{target.Object.Id}")
    Integer getId();
  }
```